# I would like just recover the value of the field that I have just entered in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like just recover the value of the field that I have just entered in jquery.
Thank you for your help

```js
 
 function test()
 {
  //????????
 }
```

```html
<form>
 <label>Price</label>
 <input type="text" name="price[]" onchange="test();"><br>
  <label>Price</label>
 <input type="text" name="price[]" onchange="test();"><br>
  <label>Price</label>
 <input type="text" name="price[]" onchange="test();">
</form>
```

Comment: Have you made an attempt to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: Yes I can recover all the values but I can not recuperate just the value that has just been entered   $("input[name='price[]']").each(function() {
      alert($(this).val());
  });

Answer (score 0):

For starters, if you're using jQuery, then use jQuery.  Remove the inline `onclick` attributes:

```
<input type="text" name="price[]">
```

And attach a single event handler to your inputs:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type="text"]').change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        // etc.
    });
});
```

Within that handler, you can refer to the input raising the event as `this` and get its value accordingly as in the code above.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/4eLrcue7/)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I had already done that does not solve my problem.
When the <input type = "text" name = price []> field is repeated more than twice.
The value received in js is always the first one and not that of the desired field

Comment: @SimpleDevNekro: Incorrect.  Follow the example I linked to in the answer and you'll see that your assertion is demonstrably wrong.  If you have different code which is resulting in an error in some way, that sounds like a good candidate for a new Stack Overflow question based on *that* code.